# Virus or Malware

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-galaxy-note

Surfing net and pop-up said "Galaxy -Your system heavily damaged by four virus!"  Address on top said, "us-philospohizing693lo.win/..."  Says if I don't remove now will cause severe damage to Sim card.  Already damaged 28%.  Click ok to download fix.

I am afraid this is a malware or something bad like that.  Don't know what to do.  Please help.  Not backed up now and 20k photos etc.   I have Samsung Galaxy Note 5.  I hit ok and stopped and did not hit "Repair fast now"  Am I messed up.  Afraid to do anything because this looks like scam, but also looks kind of official.  Don't think I have an virus protection on phone unless it came with it. About a year old. DESPARATE, PLEASE HELP.

Pop-up saying from Google said I have 4 viruses that already caused 28% damage to sim card.  Wants me to install Applock for free on Google Play and click ok to start.  Sent from >us.philosophizing693lo.win/...<  Is this legit or malware or something bad and what do I do now?  Scared and Afraid.  Second question, sent 40 minutes ago but forgot the Applock from google play part.

Answer (score 3):

There's a contradiction in terms: a popup ***from Google*** would never speak of *viruses* on Android, as there are none (i.e. no Android viruses, though there's enough of Android malware).

That looks more like malvertizing, especially as it asks you to "install some app". Do ***not*** follow that advice, do ***not*** install that app. The appearance you describe is a known malvertizing pattern, caused by malicious Javascript in one of the websites you've visited – which in addition means, avoid those websites as well.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same popup some years ago. It is surely a scam since Google doesn't provide antivirus services. Do not press anything and just close the browser or press the back button. Just to be safe you can download an antivirus app like Avast or AVG and scan your mobile phone. I wouldn't worry though.

Comment: I'd never trust any Android app calling itself "anti-virus". Why fight something that doesn't exist? That's like a "unicorn feeder": you cannot feed a unicorn unless you have one :)

Comment: @Izzy I agree with you to a point. Malware exists in android as well though.

Comment: Sure, see my answer – that's exactly what I wrote :) But naming the product "anti-virus" is mostly just playing with people's anxieties to make them use the product, which is why I don't trust those.